# Testing on an intercom amplifier

Tags: amplifier, multimeter, voltage-measurement

I am trying to test a door phone intercom amplifier. How can I test that the amplifier is not faulty with a multimeter. I have a tested fully working amplifier and another faulty one. If I measure the output voltage on both of them and then compare the values, is that a legitimate way or do I need an oscillator ?

Comment: `do i need an oscillator ?` ... why not voice or music audio input?

Comment: If you have a mobile phone then you have an oscillator. Just download a signal generator app and make a 3.5 mm audio jack and lead. Take either the L or R output and screen.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to test any audio system is with a signal generator (such as a sine wave oscillator) and a scope.  You can make basic DC measurements to see if the output DC level (before the coupling capacitor, if it has one) is centered between the supply rails, but there are many different problems that will look the same on a meter.

Please post photos of the amplifier assembly.